# My AdMob ad wont load, whether that be my personal ad unit or the test one. Ad failed to load 0

Tags: java, xml, admob

I was trying to implement the legacy API of the AdMob Rewarded Ad into Android Studio. Even though it did work once, it never actually worked again. Always telling me in the logs that my ad had failed. I have tried legacy API for rewarded ads, the new API for rewarded ads, yet I always get the same result at the end. I am using the test app id and unit id so can't be that I have not waited long enough for my AdMob account to be verified. Please help.

```
2020-07-09 15:26:45.483 5299-5299/? I/igninwallpaper: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2020-07-09 15:26:45.512 5299-5299/? I/igninwallpaper: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
2020-07-09 15:26:45.516 5299-5299/? W/igninwallpaper: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-07-09 15:26:45.799 5299-5299/com.example.reigninwallpapers D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-07-09 15:26:45.802 5299-5299/com.example.reigninwallpapers D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-07-09 15:26:45.910 5299-5324/com.example.reigninwallpapers D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2020-07-09 15:26:45.926 5299-5324/com.example.reigninwallpapers D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2020-07-09 15:26:45.936 5299-5324/com.example.reigninwallpapers D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2020-07-09 15:26:46.054 5299-5326/com.example.reigninwallpapers W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite not found.
2020-07-09 15:26:46.055 5299-5321/com.example.reigninwallpapers W/igninwallpaper: Unsupported class loader
2020-07-09 15:26:46.059 5299-5321/com.example.reigninwallpapers W/igninwallpaper: Unsupported class loader
2020-07-09 15:26:46.063 5299-5321/com.example.reigninwallpapers I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:21400
2020-07-09 15:26:46.064 5299-5321/com.example.reigninwallpapers I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 21400
2020-07-09 15:26:46.066 5299-5321/com.example.reigninwallpapers V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
2020-07-09 15:26:46.070 5299-5326/com.example.reigninwallpapers I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:13
2020-07-09 15:26:46.071 5299-5326/com.example.reigninwallpapers I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite, version >= 13
2020-07-09 15:26:46.072 5299-5326/com.example.reigninwallpapers V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
2020-07-09 15:26:46.110 5299-5326/com.example.reigninwallpapers W/igninwallpaper: Unsupported class loader
2020-07-09 15:26:46.116 5299-5326/com.example.reigninwallpapers W/igninwallpaper: Unsupported class loader
2020-07-09 15:26:46.122 5299-5299/com.example.reigninwallpapers W/igninwallpaper: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-07-09 15:26:46.123 5299-5299/com.example.reigninwallpapers W/igninwallpaper: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-07-09 15:26:46.127 5299-5321/com.example.reigninwallpapers W/igninwallpaper: Unsupported class loader
2020-07-09 15:26:46.141 5299-5326/com.example.reigninwallpapers W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite not found.
2020-07-09 15:26:46.173 5299-5321/com.example.reigninwallpapers W/igninwallpaper: Unsupported class loader
2020-07-09 15:26:46.275 5299-5299/com.example.reigninwallpapers I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 83.0.4103.44 (code 410404481)
2020-07-09 15:26:46.307 5299-5299/com.example.reigninwallpapers I/igninwallpaper: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2020-07-09 15:26:46.343 5299-5299/com.example.reigninwallpapers I/igninwallpaper: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2020-07-09 15:26:46.354 5299-5329/com.example.reigninwallpapers I/FA-Ads: App measurement initialized, version: 26016
2020-07-09 15:26:46.354 5299-5329/com.example.reigninwallpapers I/FA-Ads: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2020-07-09 15:26:46.377 5299-5299/com.example.reigninwallpapers I/cr_LibraryLoader: Loaded native library version number "83.0.4103.44"
2020-07-09 15:26:46.377 5299-5299/com.example.reigninwallpapers I/cr_CachingUmaRecorder: Flushed 3 samples from 3 histograms.
2020-07-09 15:26:46.382 5299-5299/com.example.reigninwallpapers I/TetheringManager: registerTetheringEventCallback:com.example.reigninwallpapers
2020-07-09 15:26:46.625 5299-5366/com.example.reigninwallpapers W/igninwallpaper: Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioManager;->getOutputLatency(I)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-07-09 15:26:46.637 5299-5366/com.example.reigninwallpapers W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
2020-07-09 15:26:46.662 5299-5382/com.example.reigninwallpapers D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xebb9e550, tid 5382
2020-07-09 15:26:46.677 5299-5382/com.example.reigninwallpapers D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2020-07-09 15:26:46.698 5299-5382/com.example.reigninwallpapers E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(549)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
2020-07-09 15:26:46.739 5299-5382/com.example.reigninwallpapers D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xeb9a9050: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2020-07-09 15:26:46.742 5299-5382/com.example.reigninwallpapers D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xeb9a9050: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xbc2c3530) (first time)
2020-07-09 15:26:46.763 5299-5299/com.example.reigninwallpapers I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
2020-07-09 15:26:46.769 5299-5382/com.example.reigninwallpapers E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(549)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
2020-07-09 15:26:46.806 5299-5382/com.example.reigninwallpapers I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
2020-07-09 15:26:46.810 5299-5382/com.example.reigninwallpapers W/cr_MediaCodecUtil: HW encoder for video/avc is not available on this device.
2020-07-09 15:26:46.827 5299-5382/com.example.reigninwallpapers D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xeb9aa6a0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2020-07-09 15:26:46.941 5299-5330/com.example.reigninwallpapers D/zzex: File /data/user/0/com.example.reigninwallpapers/cache/1584479576572.dex not found. No need for deletion
2020-07-09 15:26:46.959 5299-5299/com.example.reigninwallpapers I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:21400
2020-07-09 15:26:46.959 5299-5299/com.example.reigninwallpapers I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 21400
2020-07-09 15:26:46.959 5299-5299/com.example.reigninwallpapers V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
2020-07-09 15:26:47.010 5299-5426/com.example.reigninwallpapers W/Ads: Invoke Firebase method getInstance error.
2020-07-09 15:26:47.010 5299-5426/com.example.reigninwallpapers W/Ads: The Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase. Admob/Firebase integration requires the latest Firebase SDK jar, but Firebase SDK is either missing or out of date
2020-07-09 15:26:47.173 5299-5299/com.example.reigninwallpapers I/Choreographer: Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-07-09 15:26:47.196 5299-5322/com.example.reigninwallpapers D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xebba50f0, tid 5322
2020-07-09 15:26:47.204 5299-5322/com.example.reigninwallpapers D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2020-07-09 15:26:47.204 5299-5322/com.example.reigninwallpapers W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2020-07-09 15:26:47.220 5299-5322/com.example.reigninwallpapers D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xeb9ab740: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2020-07-09 15:26:47.226 5299-5322/com.example.reigninwallpapers D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xeb9ab740: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xbc2d07d0) (first time)
2020-07-09 15:26:47.256 5299-5322/com.example.reigninwallpapers I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
2020-07-09 15:26:47.258 5299-5322/com.example.reigninwallpapers D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2020-07-09 15:26:47.258 5299-5322/com.example.reigninwallpapers D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xebba8330, tid 5322
2020-07-09 15:26:47.259 5299-5322/com.example.reigninwallpapers D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
2020-07-09 15:26:47.259 5299-5322/com.example.reigninwallpapers D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3f66da000 size 0x2000
2020-07-09 15:26:47.265 5299-5322/com.example.reigninwallpapers D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
<br>
2020-07-09 15:26:47.379 5299-5299/com.example.reigninwallpapers I/Ads: <b>Ad failed to load : 0</b>
<br>
2020-07-09 15:26:47.526 5299-5313/com.example.reigninwallpapers I/igninwallpaper: WaitForGcToComplete blocked Background on None for 9.520ms
2020-07-09 15:26:52.579 5299-5329/com.example.reigninwallpapers W/ConnectionTracker: Exception thrown while unbinding
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lm@e211662
        at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1729)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1874)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:792)
        at ce.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):1)
        at ce.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):5)
        at ln.A(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):10)
        at ky.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):3)
        at dy.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):2)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at iw.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):15)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAd;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RewardedVideoAdListener {
    private RewardedVideoAd mRewardedVideoAd;
private String UNIT_ID ="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";//change to your unit ID
private String APP_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713";// change to your app id.



   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MobileAds.initialize(this, UNIT_ID);

        // Use an activity context to get the rewarded video instance.
        mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);


       loadRewardedVideoAd();
    }
   

 private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd(UNIT_ID,
        new AdRequest.Builder().build());
}

}
```

Set up event notifications.

```
@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewarded! currency: " + reward.getType() + "  amount: " +
            reward.getAmount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Reward the user.
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoCompleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Display a rewarded video ad to ensure that a rewarded video ad has finished loading before attempting to display it. The isLoaded() method indicates if the rewarded video ad request has been successfully fulfilled.

```
if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
    mRewardedVideoAd.show();
}
```

RewardedVideoAdListener to reload an ad this method is a handy place to load a new rewarded video ad after displaying the previous one.

```
@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    // Load the next rewarded video ad.
    loadRewardedVideoAd();
}
```

Forward lifecycle events better to be used.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    mRewardedVideoAd.resume(this);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    mRewardedVideoAd.pause(this);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mRewardedVideoAd.destroy(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```